# Working on pre-operation plug-in to update "Modified By" field in MSCRM -- Need help fixing code

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to update the "Modified By" field based on a text field called "Prepared By", which contains the name of a user.  I've created a pre-operation plug-in to do this and believe I am close to done.  However, the "Modified By" field is still not successfully getting updated.  I am relatively new to coding and CRM, and could use some help modifying the code and figuring out how I can get this to work.

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace TimClassLibrary1.Plugins
{
    public class CreateUpdateContact : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
            var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            var factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            var service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            tracingService.Trace("Start plugin");

            tracingService.Trace("Validate Target");
            if (!context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") || !(context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity))
                return;

            tracingService.Trace("Retrieve Target");
            var target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            String message = context.MessageName.ToLower();

            SetCreatedByAndModifiedBy(tracingService, service, target, message);
        }

        private void SetCreatedByAndModifiedBy(ITracingService tracingService, IOrganizationService service, Entity target, string message)
        {
            tracingService.Trace("Start SetPriceList");
            tracingService.Trace("Validate Message is Create or Update");
            if (!message.Equals("create", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !message.Equals("update", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return;

            tracingService.Trace("Retrieve Attributes");
            var createdByReference = target.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_createdby");
            var modifiedByReference = target.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_modifiedby");

            tracingService.Trace("Retrieve And Set User for Created By");
            RetrieveAndSetUser(tracingService, service, target, createdByReference, "createdby");

            tracingService.Trace("Retrieve And Set User for Modified By");
            RetrieveAndSetUser(tracingService, service, target, modifiedByReference, "modifiedby");
        }

        private void RetrieveAndSetUser(ITracingService tracingService, IOrganizationService service, Entity target, EntityReference reference, string targetAttribute)
        {
            tracingService.Trace("Validating Reference");
            if (reference == null)
                return;

            tracingService.Trace("Retrieving and Validating User");
            var user = RetrieveUserByName(service, reference.Name, new ColumnSet(false));
            if (user == null)
                return;

            tracingService.Trace("Setting Target Attribute");
            target[targetAttribute] = user.ToEntityReference();
        }

        private Entity RetrieveUserByName(IOrganizationService service, string name, ColumnSet columns)
        {
            var query = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = "systemuser",
                ColumnSet = columns,
                Criteria = new FilterExpression
                {
                    FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                    Conditions =
                    {
                        new ConditionExpression
                        {
                            AttributeName = "fullname",
                            Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                            Values = { name }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var retrieveResponse = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
            if (retrieveResponse.Entities.Count == 1)
            {
                return retrieveResponse.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do get use from method Retreiveusernyname then you have to use below code

```
target[“modifiedby”] = new EntityRefrence(user.logicalname,user.id);
```

Comment: He already appears to be setting the entity references correctly.

Comment: He is returning entity 1st record and directly converting it into entityref rather crate object of entityref and pass guid and logical name

Comment: There is logically no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your update, however you are taking a complicated and unnecessary step with your RetrieveUserByName() method. You already have EntityReference objects from your new_createdby and new_modifiedby fields, you can simply assign those to the target:

```
if (message.Equals("create", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    target["createdby"] = target["new_createdby];
}
else if (message.Equals("update", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    target["modifiedby"] = target["new_modifiedby];
}
```

If new_createdby and new_modifiedby are not entity references, then that would explain why your existing code does not work, if they are, then use my approach.